# 401: unauthorized (it contains bearer token)

Tags: authorization, postman, access-token

- Login module is working and creating users with token 201 created
- Receipts route had worked with the same code before but now response is 401
- using Postman (Authorization & Bearer: xcvbnm) has been put
- Here is my code

  server.js

  const express = require('express')
  require('./db/mongoose')
  const userRouter = require('./routes/user')
  const receiptRouter = require('./routes/receipt')

  const app = express()
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4003
  app.use(express.json())
  app.use(userRouter)
  app.use(receiptRouter)
  app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log('Server is up on port ' + port)
     })

  const Receipt = require('./models/receipt')
  const User = require('./models/user')

Receipts Route

```
router.post('/receipts', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const receipt = new Receipt({
        ...req.body,
        owner: req.user._id
    })
  try {
        await receipt.save()
        res.status(201).send(receipt)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

Receipt Schema
    const Receipt = mongoose.model('Receipt', {
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    })

```
Auth module
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'Mango@123')
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }

        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you heed to pass token in the header which is available in Headers tab. 
The following link may be useful for you
http://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2019/09/implement-jwt-authentication-token-with-web-api-in-nodejs.html

Comment: Thanks Laxman, but i already am passing the token in the headers moreover i also tried it with inheriting authorization form parent making sure the token put is same as token generated